Solving environment failed and ResolvePackageNotFound in Conda
I try to run:
conda env create --file environment.yaml


after that I get the following result:
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h166bdaf_8
  - libwebp-base==1.2.4=h166bdaf_0
  - mysql-common==8.0.32=ha901b37_0
  - markupsafe==2.1.1=py39hb9d737c_2
  - llvmlite==0.39.1=py39h7d9a04d_1
  - levenshtein==0.20.9=py39h227be39_0
  - zlib==1.2.13=h166bdaf_4
  - libgcc-ng==12.2.0=h65d4601_19
  - zlib-ng==2.0.6=h166bdaf_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.6.2=py39hf9fd14e_0
  - contourpy==1.0.6=py39hf939315_0
  - tk==8.6.12=h27826a3_0
  - lz4==4.2.0=py39h724f13c_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp==1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - zstd==1.5.2=h6239696_4
  - mkl==2020.4=h726a3e6_304
  - pthread-stubs==0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - brotli==1.0.9=h166bdaf_8
  - umap-learn==0.5.3=py39hf3d152e_0
  - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h166bdaf_8
  - pillow==9.1.1=py39hae2aec6_1
  - libprotobuf==3.21.12=h3eb15da_0
  - cryptography==39.0.0=py39h079d5ae_0
  - scikit-image==0.19.3=py39h1832856_1
  - jupyter_core==5.1.1=py39hf3d152e_0
  - charls==2.3.4=h9c3ff4c_0
  - libavif==0.10.1=h166bdaf_0
  - grpcio==1.51.1=py39h8c60046_0
  - libnghttp2==1.47.0=hff17c54_1
  - h5py==3.7.0=nompi_py39h817c9c5_102
  - debugpy==1.6.4=py39h5a03fae_0
  - lame==3.100=h166bdaf_1003
  - blosc==1.21.3=hafa529b_0
  - libzlib==1.2.13=h166bdaf_4
  - mysql-libs==8.0.32=hd7da12d_0
  - libhwloc==2.8.0=h32351e8_1
  - libxml2==2.10.3=h7463322_0
  - eigen==3.4.0=h4bd325d_0
  - brunsli==0.1=h9c3ff4c_0
  - xorg-libxau==1.0.9=h7f98852_0
  - mysql-connector-python==8.0.31=py39hfa0bd35_2
  - cudatoolkit==11.3.1=h2bc3f7f_2
  - zfp==0.5.5=h9c3ff4c_8
  - libllvm11==11.1.0=he0ac6c6_5
  - _openmp_mutex==4.5=2_kmp_llvm
  - pandoc==2.19.2=h32600fe_1
  - numpy==1.23.5=py39h3d75532_0
  - ca-certificates==2022.12.7=ha878542_0
  - unicodedata2==15.0.0=py39hb9d737c_0
  - libitk==5.3.0=hcedbc38_0
  - libabseil==20220623.0=cxx17_h05df665_6
  - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1=py39h3ccb8fc_4
  - nettle==3.6=he412f7d_0
  - lz4-c==1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_1
  - libedit==3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - aom==3.3.0=h27087fc_1
  - libgrpc==1.51.1=h30feacc_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0=py39hb9d737c_3
  - libxcb==1.13=h7f98852_1004
  - gnutls==3.6.13=h85f3911_1
  - pyzmq==24.0.1=py39headdf64_1
  - cbgen==1.0.1=py39hb9d737c_2
  - expat==2.5.0=h27087fc_0
  - hdf5==1.12.2=nompi_h4df4325_101
  - libzopfli==1.0.3=h9c3ff4c_0
  - libdeflate==1.12=h166bdaf_0
  - simpleitk==2.2.1=py39hdaa313e_1
  - giflib==5.2.1=h36c2ea0_2
  - libgfortran-ng==12.2.0=h69a702a_19
  - c-ares==1.18.1=h7f98852_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - libev==4.33=h516909a_1
  - rapidfuzz==2.13.7=py39h227be39_0
  - almosthere==2.0.2=h46c0cb4_1
  - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h166bdaf_8
  - keyutils==1.6.1=h166bdaf_0
  - tornado==6.2=py39hb9d737c_1
  - imagecodecs==2022.2.22=py39hfcd4fa2_6
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h36c2ea0_1
  - cffi==1.15.1=py39he91dace_3
  - libstdcxx-ng==12.2.0=h46fd767_19
  - lcms2==2.14=h6ed2654_0
  - promise==2.3=py39hf3d152e_7
  - libpng==1.6.39=h753d276_0
  - icu==70.1=h27087fc_0
  - psutil==5.9.4=py39hb9d737c_0
  - aiohttp==3.8.3=py39hb9d737c_1
  - fftw==3.3.10=nompi_hf0379b8_106
  - _libgcc_mutex==0.1=conda_forge
  - yaml==0.2.5=h7f98852_2
  - libgfortran5==12.2.0=h337968e_19
  - protobuf==4.21.12=py39h227be39_0
  - setuptools==59.5.0=py39hf3d152e_0
  - yarl==1.8.2=py39hb9d737c_0
  - python==3.9.15=hba424b6_0_cpython
  - freetype==2.12.1=hca18f0e_1
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py39hb9d737c_1005
  - lerc==3.0=h9c3ff4c_0
  - llvm-openmp==15.0.6=he0ac6c6_0
  - libnsl==2.0.0=h7f98852_0
  - pywavelets==1.3.0=py39h2ae25f5_2
  - gmp==6.2.1=h58526e2_0
  - ncurses==6.3=h27087fc_1
  - bgen-reader==4.0.8=py39hf3d152e_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.39=hcc3a1bd_1
  - libtiff==4.4.0=hc85c160_1
  - bgen==4.1.3=ha0ad84f_0
  - wrapt==1.14.1=py39hb9d737c_1
  - openh264==2.1.1=h780b84a_0
  - scikit-learn==1.2.0=py39h86b2a18_0
  - kiwisolver==1.4.4=py39hf939315_1
  - scipy==1.8.1=py39h8ba3f38_2
  - libiconv==1.17=h166bdaf_0
  - libssh2==1.10.0=hf14f497_3
  - zeromq==4.3.4=h9c3ff4c_1
  - pytorch==1.11.0=py3.9_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0
  - ffmpeg==4.3=hf484d3e_0
  - cytoolz==0.12.0=py39hb9d737c_1
  - libsqlite==3.40.0=h753d276_0
  - openssl==3.0.7=h0b41bf4_1
  - brotli-bin==1.0.9=h166bdaf_8
  - msgpack-python==1.0.4=py39hf939315_1
  - jpeg==9e=h166bdaf_2
  - brotli-python==1.0.9=py39h5a03fae_8
  - jxrlib==1.1=h7f98852_2
  - statsmodels==0.13.5=py39h2ae25f5_2
  - c-blosc2==2.6.1=hf91038e_0
  - openjpeg==2.4.0=hb52868f_1
  - libuv==1.44.2=h166bdaf_0
  - frozenlist==1.3.3=py39hb9d737c_0
  - libwebp==1.2.4=h522a892_0
  - re2==2022.06.01=h27087fc_1
  - snappy==1.1.9=hbd366e4_2
  - libcurl==7.87.0=hdc1c0ab_0
  - krb5==1.20.1=h81ceb04_0
  - pyyaml==6.0=py39hb9d737c_5
  - multidict==6.0.4=py39h72bdee0_0
  - numba==0.56.4=py39h61ddf18_0
  - libaec==1.0.6=h9c3ff4c_0
  - readline==8.1.2=h0f457ee_0
  - pyrsistent==0.19.2=py39hb9d737c_0
  - libuuid==2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - tbb==2021.7.0=h924138e_1
  - xz==5.2.6=h166bdaf_0
  - fonttools==4.38.0=py39hb9d737c_1
  - pandas==1.5.2=py39h4661b88_0
  - setproctitle==1.3.2=py39hb9d737c_1
  - libffi==3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - cfitsio==4.1.0=hd9d235c_0

Why this problem occurred? How I can fix it to run this project at following address:
https://github.com/paulhager/MMCL-Tabular-Imaging/blob/main/environment.yaml
I try to add Channels but not works...

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

What is your operating system?

@James Win 10 is my OS

The issue is that all of the packages are for a Linux-64 architecture.  You will need to use a requirements file with packages that run on Windows or you need to install WSL2 to run Linux within Windows.
From looking through the imports, here are the packages that are actually imported:
name: selfsuper
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - hydra-core
  - ipykernel
  - jupyter
  - lightly
  - lightly-utils
  - lightning-bolts
  - numpy
  - omegaconf
  - pandas
  - pytorch
  - pytorch-lightning
  - scikit-learn
  - seaborn
  - torchmetrics
  - torchvision
  - wandb

